# An adapter for RecylcerView returns index of -1 when calling 'notifyDataSetChanged()' on setOnFocusChangeListener in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a RecyclerView which contains a list of EditText in it.

In the list of EditText, if any of text is duplicated to others, the background of EditText should be changed like red-border.
The function for a duplicate check is placed in setOnFocusChangeListener() on each of EditText.

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseViewHolder {
   val baseViewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType)
   val EditText = baseViewHolder.findViewById(R.id.editText)

   EditText.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->    
      if(!hasFocus) {
         // check if text duplicated
         checkFunc()
      }

      notifyDataSetChanged()
   }

   return baseViewHolder
}
```

The problem is, when calling notifyDataSetChanged(), 'ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException' exception prints and app crashed.

below is the specific error msg.

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=36; index=-1
> at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:439)
> at.test.ui.activity.EditTextTestAdapter$onCreateViewHolder$1.onFocusChange(EditTextTestAdapter.kt:21)
> at android.view.View.onFocusChanged(View.java:6921)
> at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged(TextView.java:9601)
> at android.view.View.clearFocusInternal(View.java:6758)
> at android.view.View.unFocus(View.java:6791)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.unFocus(ViewGroup.java:1086)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:5207)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewAt(ViewGroup.java:5170)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$5.removeViewAt(RecyclerView.java:882)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.ChildHelper.removeViewAt(ChildHelper.java:168)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.removeViewAt(RecyclerView.java:8639)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.scrapOrRecycleView(RecyclerView.java:9209)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.detachAndScrapAttachedViews(RecyclerView.java:9195)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:630)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1867)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.focusSearch(RecyclerView.java:2797)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:960)
> at android.view.View.focusSearch(View.java:10131)
> at android.widget.TextView.onCreateInputConnection(TextView.java:7517)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.onCreateInputConnection(AppCompatEditText.java:195)
> at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:1237)
> at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.onPostWindowFocus(InputMethodManager.java:1538)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3866)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

I don't know the exact reason for what makes the -1 index value from notifyDataSetChanged().

If anyone could help me with this, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you share the code of the checkFunc() ?

Comment: I don't have it yet, though my app crashed because of notifyDataSetChanged() method.